# Django admin site: how to get formfield_overrides to override models.CharField with choices

Tags: django

In `models.py`

```
class AnnualReport(models.Model):
    SCRAPED = 'scraped'
    CHECKED = 'checked'
    CHECKED_AND_RESTATED = 'restated'
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        (SCRAPED, 'Scraped'),
        (CHECKED, 'Checked'),
        (CHECKED_AND_RESTATED, 'Restated'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default=CHECKED)
```

I want to override the style in `status`'s form field in admin site. But I couldn't find the right selector for `CharField` with choices. As below, `models.CharField` didn't render custom effects.

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.CharField: {
        ...
    },
}
```

Moreover, I have tried `TypedChoiceField` and `ChoiceField` which didn't work either.

So my question is which is the right selector? Thank you!

Comment: Since you have set choices keyword for CharField, it uses Select widget for CharField defaultly, so it works as your mind, and do not need formfield_overrides.

Comment: but I want to adjust the width of the Select element by setting the `attrs`.

Comment: For example, I have customized some fields like this `models.DecimalField: {'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'8', 'style': 'text-align:right;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;border-radius:0;background:transparent;', }), },` in the `formfield_overrides`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## one way to solve it with overriding a method of ModelAdmin

```
class AnnualReportAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # do your handling here

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if field.label.lower() == 'status':
            field.widget.attrs.update({'size':'50','width':'100px'})
        return field
    # or
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        form.fields['status'].widget.attrs.update({'size':'50','width':'100px'})
        return form

admin.site.register(AnnualReport, AnnualReportAdmin)
```